# How to work with maven in mule?

Tags: maven, mule, maven-plugin

I have just created one simple mule project with maven.

Below is the sample code. I don't modify pom file what ever repository is there just going ahead not using any external settings.xml.

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<flow name="newFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/hi" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger message="logging......" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

I have done maven set up and everything in anypoint studio but when i run the interface getiing below error message, please help.

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T22:11:47+05:30)
Maven home: D:\Softwares\apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_112, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"

[13:25:06] Running: mvn clean package -DskipMunitTests
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Mule new Application 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.mulesoft.muleesb:mule-core-ee:jar:3.8.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules:mule-module-spring-config-ee:jar:3.8.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.mule.transports:mule-transport-file:jar:3.8.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.mule.transports:mule-transport-http:jar:3.8.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports:mule-transport-jdbc-ee:jar:3.8.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports:mule-transport-jms-ee:jar:3.8.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.mule.transports:mule-transport-vm:jar:3.8.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.mule.modules:mule-module-scripting:jar:3.8.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.mule.modules:mule-module-xml:jar:3.8.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.mule.tests:mule-tests-functional:jar:3.8.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mule/modules/mule-module-http/3.8.3/mule-module-http-3.8.3.pom
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/org/mule/modules/mule-module-http/3.8.3/mule-module-http-3.8.3.pom
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mule/modules/mule-module-http/3.8.3/mule-module-http-3.8.3.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.mule.modules:mule-module-http:jar:3.8.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.mule.modules:mule-module-spring-config:jar:3.8.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/mulesoft/muleesb/mule-core-ee/3.8.3/mule-core-ee-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/mulesoft/muleesb/modules/mule-module-spring-config-ee/3.8.3/mule-module-spring-config-ee-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mule/transports/mule-transport-file/3.8.3/mule-transport-file-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mule/transports/mule-transport-http/3.8.3/mule-transport-http-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/mulesoft/muleesb/transports/mule-transport-jdbc-ee/3.8.3/mule-transport-jdbc-ee-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/mulesoft/muleesb/transports/mule-transport-jms-ee/3.8.3/mule-transport-jms-ee-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mule/transports/mule-transport-vm/3.8.3/mule-transport-vm-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mule/modules/mule-module-scripting/3.8.3/mule-module-scripting-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mule/modules/mule-module-xml/3.8.3/mule-module-xml-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mule/tests/mule-tests-functional/3.8.3/mule-tests-functional-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mule/modules/mule-module-http/3.8.3/mule-module-http-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.8.3/mule-module-spring-config-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/com/mulesoft/muleesb/mule-core-ee/3.8.3/mule-core-ee-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/com/mulesoft/muleesb/modules/mule-module-spring-config-ee/3.8.3/mule-module-spring-config-ee-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/org/mule/transports/mule-transport-file/3.8.3/mule-transport-file-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/org/mule/transports/mule-transport-http/3.8.3/mule-transport-http-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/com/mulesoft/muleesb/transports/mule-transport-jdbc-ee/3.8.3/mule-transport-jdbc-ee-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/com/mulesoft/muleesb/transports/mule-transport-jms-ee/3.8.3/mule-transport-jms-ee-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/org/mule/transports/mule-transport-vm/3.8.3/mule-transport-vm-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/org/mule/modules/mule-module-scripting/3.8.3/mule-module-scripting-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/org/mule/modules/mule-module-xml/3.8.3/mule-module-xml-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/org/mule/tests/mule-tests-functional/3.8.3/mule-tests-functional-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/org/mule/modules/mule-module-http/3.8.3/mule-module-http-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.8.3/mule-module-spring-config-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/mulesoft/muleesb/mule-core-ee/3.8.3/mule-core-ee-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/mulesoft/muleesb/modules/mule-module-spring-config-ee/3.8.3/mule-module-spring-config-ee-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mule/transports/mule-transport-file/3.8.3/mule-transport-file-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mule/transports/mule-transport-http/3.8.3/mule-transport-http-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/mulesoft/muleesb/transports/mule-transport-jdbc-ee/3.8.3/mule-transport-jdbc-ee-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/mulesoft/muleesb/transports/mule-transport-jms-ee/3.8.3/mule-transport-jms-ee-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mule/transports/mule-transport-vm/3.8.3/mule-transport-vm-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mule/modules/mule-module-scripting/3.8.3/mule-module-scripting-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mule/modules/mule-module-xml/3.8.3/mule-module-xml-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mule/tests/mule-tests-functional/3.8.3/mule-tests-functional-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mule/modules/mule-module-http/3.8.3/mule-module-http-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mule/modules/mule-module-spring-config/3.8.3/mule-module-spring-config-3.8.3.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.163 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-13T13:25:24+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/161M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project new: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:new:mule:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.mulesoft.muleesb:mule-core-ee:jar:3.8.3, com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules:mule-module-spring-config-ee:jar:3.8.3, org.mule.transports:mule-transport-file:jar:3.8.3, org.mule.transports:mule-transport-http:jar:3.8.3, com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports:mule-transport-jdbc-ee:jar:3.8.3, com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports:mule-transport-jms-ee:jar:3.8.3, org.mule.transports:mule-transport-vm:jar:3.8.3, org.mule.modules:mule-module-scripting:jar:3.8.3, org.mule.modules:mule-module-xml:jar:3.8.3, org.mule.tests:mule-tests-functional:jar:3.8.3, org.mule.modules:mule-module-http:jar:3.8.3, org.mule.modules:mule-module-spring-config:jar:3.8.3: Could not find artifact com.mulesoft.muleesb:mule-core-ee:jar:3.8.3 in Central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Comment: See the docs: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/configuring-maven-to-work-with-mule-esb

Comment: Hi, I have gone through the document. is that settings file mandatory ? is there any free repository is there to connect ? In pom.xml i could see a repository <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url> why again additional repository is required ?

Comment: I guess they don't publish their releases on Maven Central (the default available repo in a Maven installation), so you do have to add another repository to be able to download their artifacts.

Comment: is there any free repository to which i can connect and get resolved the dependency issues ? i think i need credential to connect any repository.

Comment: Well that http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/ repository seems to be free

Answer (score 0):

As per log failures its failing for EE repositories, which as meant for enterprise version. You can resolved it in two ways add enterprise credentials and repository mentioned at [referencing-mulesoft-s-enterprise-repositories](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/configuring-maven-to-work-with-mule-esb#referencing-mulesoft-s-enterprise-repositories) or remove ee dependencies and add community dependencies with settings configutaion mentioned at [referencing-the-open-source-mulesoft-repositories](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/configuring-maven-to-work-with-mule-esb#referencing-the-open-source-mulesoft-repositories)

Comment: Hi, i have configured settings.xml as mentioned in link but getting authorization issues. "Access denied to: https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/com/mulesoft/muleesb/mule-core-ee/3.8.3/mule-core-ee-3.8.3.pom "

Comment: Have you provided the nexus credentials? Anypoint credential will not work. If you dont have it try with community version. You can refer community dependencies from [Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=mule)